# Html with javascript-search

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search application in html with javascript.In that i used select & option(select box).I want to retrieve the values from access database to selectbox.How can i do this with array?i also want to get the count of the option.The below not working correctly.How can i do this.any one knows please help me.Thank you.

```
var myselect=(selinstal.value);

for(var i=0;i<(select2.option.length);i++)
{
    myarray[i]=myselect;
    rs(myarray);  
    //document.write(rs(0));
}

<select id="Select2" style="width: 152px" name="selinstal">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by something like this.

I haven't tested it, but it should do..

To get the selected option:
`document.getElementById("Select2").options[document.getElementById("Select2").selectedIndex].value`

To get an array with options:
`document.getElementById("Select2").options`

Comment: How can i replace this code?

"for(var i=0;i<(select2.option.length);i++)"

Comment: By the exact code i gave you in my answer... ? `var options = document.getElementById("Select2").options;` then use `for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++)`

Comment: how can i fill values from access database to selectbox in html with javascript?please assist me.me new with javascript.

Comment: Try using Google and not just wait here for some working code-samples... some resources... http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial005.html and http://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&source=hp&q=add+select+option+javascript&btnG=Google+zoeken&meta=&aq=0&oq=add+select+option+&fp=974cfba000896278

Answer (score 0):

Devassy,

Your question is not very clear. If it is how to retrieve the values from access database to selectbox , you should prob do it at the server side code by enumerating the records over the select options.

If it is about how to find the total count of the options for the select, use what Ben has suggested.

document.getElementById("Select2").options.length

Also make sure that the above script executes after the select element is loaded in to the DOM ie after window.onload is invoked.